# Php/Mysql database daily report

Tags: php, mysql, wampserver

I'm new in php/mysql. I'm creating a simple webpage showing tables/data from my database(wamp). My problem is I want this data I input in the database table to save daily and to show them  by calling the specific date/time. I'm lost I need a little help to put me in the right direction. Than you somuch!!

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: hmm my problem is i want the database table to save daily report. so i can call it to show the data i input in specific day. for example i input data on april 9. i want it to be save so i can call it on other webpages. only the data i input on april 9 or specific date.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: No sir. That is my problem I don't have any idea how to do it. I have done a little research on the net but i cant find specific answer. You have to forgive me i'm a newbie in php/mysql.

Comment: FYI, we are not supposed to give you the full code. Learn some basics of php and mysql and try it yourself. If you face any specific problem, show some code and then we might be able to help you.

Comment: yes sir i know im not asking for full codes.i already coded the basic CRUD. thats why im asking the way how to save and view specific date because thats where i got lost. i dont know if i shud use event or trigger or what to save the daily transaction and preview it by calling specific date and time. anyway Mr Abir reply that i shud use time stamp. im trying it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your date_time field Datatype is timestamp.

If you want to show data from table using specific date/time, try it

```
SELECT field_name1, field_name2, field_name3 
    WHERE date_time_field= '2014-04-10 16:14:54' 
    ORDER BY date_time_field DESC
```